# What components require state, understanding react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Currently I'm building a Web App and looking to understand how state is implemented in a components hierarchy. Below is the structure of a component and it's children

Store

```
<div>
    <StoreHeader change={handleChange} search={searchInput}/>
    <QuickLinks/>
    <LongAdBanner />
    <SearchGridContainer itemList={itemData} itemGroups={itemGroups} radioChange=
{handleRadioChange} />
</div>
```

SearchGridContainer

```
   <div className={styles.searchGridContainer}>
      <SearchFilterPanel itemGroups={props.itemGroups} radioChange={props.radioChange}/>
      <SearchResultsPanel itemList={props.itemList}/>
   </div>
```

SearchFilterPanel

```
 <div className={styles.searchFilterPanel}>
            <h1>Filters</h1>
            <FiltersTable itemGroups={props.itemGroups} changeGroupFilter={props.changeGroupFilter} radioChange={props.radioChange}/>
 </div>
```

FilterTable

```
const FiltersTable = (props) => {


    //Output a list of all item groups that are able to be filtered.
    const groupFilter = props.itemGroups.map( (itemGroup,index) => 
    <li key={index} className={styles.filterOption}>
        <input 
        id={itemGroup}
        className={styles.filterCheckBox} 
        type="checkbox" 
        name='filterOption'
        onClick={props.radioChange}
        value={itemGroup.group}
        
        ></input>
        <label for={itemGroup.group}>{itemGroup.group}</label>
    </li>);

    return(
        <div className={styles.filtersTable}>
            <ul>
                {groupFilter}
            </ul>
        </div>
    ) }
```

---

Currently I'm building all of the applications state into the main Store component, i.e  all handler methods. I have read the [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html). It states

> Figure out the absolute minimal representation of the state your
> application needs and compute everything else you need on-demand

Should I be implementing state into the component that has the checkboxes to apply a search filter (`FilterTable`) or keep that handlers inside the `Store` component and pass them down?

The only things that should require state in my application is the users search input and when the user selected a search filter from the listed options.

Comment: You should do what makes sense for your components! Generally though, the component should have state if it has data that must change that is not needed by any other component (other than a child of that one). E.g. you have a dialog component with a checkbox, but the state of the checkbox is only submitted when you press a button. The checkbox is irrelevant to any other component, but you keep it in state while the dialog is up so when they press the submit button on the dialogue, you knoe the correct value for the checkbox to do something with.

Comment: If you find yourself passing state down like crazy all over your app, its highly likely you would benefit from using a state manager lile redux so you can access state from any component. https://redux.js.org/

Comment: React state, like just about any other variable declaration, should be declared where it limits the scope as much as possible. If no other component/element in the app cares about the intermediate checkbox values, then it probably should be in app state. This is the main purpose of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) when you need to elevate the scope of "chunk of state".

Comment: So for example my route to Demo renders the Store Component which has state because it needs to keep track of the items being rendered in the ResultsPanel. It gets the results by passing the handleChange to StoreHeader that contains the search input. Now I also want to keep track of the selected group filter from the FilterPanel, which requires some user action. Should state be implemented into the FilterPanel instead of passing handlers down to handle the selected filter from FilterTable. Seems like there is a lot of handler passing being done in this situation from the Store component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a super-contrived example using the *strict* structure you have given us here. Hopefully it will help explain how to think about state placement, then we can adjust it slightly to what you *probably* want in actual fact.

```
| Store
  | StoreHeader
    state: searchInput
    handlers: handleChange
  | QuickLinks
  | LongAdBanner
  | SearchGridContainer
    | SearchFilterPanel
      | FiltersTable
        state: itemGroups
        handlers: radioChange
    | SearchResultsPanel
      state: itemList
```

I've moved everything deeper into the component where it is actually used, because in the code you shared no two components consume the same props. However, I'm obviously making some assumptions here because I can't see what you're actually doing to your data with those change handlers. If the `searchInput` and `itemGroups` changes affect `itemList`, as I expect they do, then this is not going to work.

So then the question becomes: how low (or deep, depending on how you think about component structure) in the tree can we keep everything while still enabling the components to function? What is the minimum amount of state sharing that needs to take place for that to happen? Here is a second structure where I make some educated guesses as to what this might be.

```
| Store
  state: searchInput
  handlers: handleChange
  | StoreHeader
    props: searchInput, handleChange
  | QuickLinks
  | LongAdBanner
  | SearchGridContainer
    state: itemGroups, itemList
    handlers: radioChange
    props: searchInput
    | SearchFilterPanel
      props: itemGroups, radioChange
      | FiltersTable
        props: itemGroups, radioChange
    | SearchResultsPanel
      props: itemList
```

The main difference between this and your original structure is that we've moved everything to do with `items` inside `SearchGridContainer`. The other components - `StoreHeader`, `QuickLinks`, and `LongAdBanner` - have nothing to do with them, and assuming your `Store` does not render anything else that requires them, they do not need to belong there.

Again, the assumption I'm making here is that `itemGroups` affects the rendering of `itemList`, as does `searchInput`, which is why we are now bringing the latter in as a prop instead of doing all our computing in the top level `Store` component.

You might also realise from this that `FiltersTable` does not even need to exist as a separate component, because `SearchFilterPanel` is capable of doing all the presentation work by itself. `SearchGridContainer` acts as the controller for both it and `SearchResultsPanel`.

Comment: I've accepted the answer at is explains how exactly to determine where we should put state within components. You assumptions were spot on that the itemGroups and searchInput determine how the list is rendered. Helps me understand what I should look for when structuring components with state. Appreciate the clear explanation as I'm still relatively new to React.